# Select results from A table & insert into another table - Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In my stored procedure, i have a select statement which will return more than one row of results. And i would want to insert those results into another table.
When i run the stored procedure, there are two rows of result returned from select statement, but it only insert one row of result instead of two into sendemail table.
Can anyone help on this? thanks

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE
        @newid int,
        @Name nvarchar (50),
        @Email nvarchar(50),
        @ExpiryDate varchar(50)

    SET @newid = 0

    --Get results
    SELECT @newid = b.[Id]
    , @Name = c.[Name]
    , @Email = b.[Email]
    , @ExpiryDate = a.AccountExpiryDate
    FROM Account a
    LEFT JOIN Customer b ON c.[Id] = a.[CustomerId]
    LEFT JOIN VIP c on c.[Id] = b.[VIPId]
    WHERE a.[AccountExpiryDate] Between Cast(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(d, 30, GETDATE()) AS DATE)

    --Insert into send email table if return results
    IF(@newid > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[SendEmail]
            VALUES (
                 5
                ,'test@hotmail.com'
                ,'Test'
                ,@Email
                ,@Name
                ,NULL
                ,NULL
                ,''
                ,NULL
                ,'Test Email'
                ,'<p>
                    Hi ' + @Name + ',<br /><br />
                    Your account will be expired on ' + @ExpiryDate + '.
                </p>'
                ,NULL
                ,NULL
                ,0
                ,GETUTCDATE()
                ,NULL
                ,1
                ,NULL
                ,1)

    END
END
```

Comment: You only have one insert so only one row. You want to look at the form "INSERT INTO...SELECT...". This will do inserts from results of the select. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp Try that and then can ask more specific questions on syntax if needed.

Comment: Okay. It's working now. Thanks @asantaballa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SendEmail] ( column list goes here )
    SELECT 5, 'test@hotmail.com', 'Test', c.[Email], v.[Name], '',
           'Test Email',
           '<p>
                    Hi ' + v.[Name] + ',<br /><br />
                    Your account will be expired on ' + cast(a.AccountExpiryDate as varchar(255)) + '.
                </p>',
               0, GETUTCDATE(), 1, 1)           
   FROM Account a LEFT JOIN
        Customer c
        ON c.[Id] = a.[CustomerId] LEFT JOIN
        VIP v
        ON v.[Id] = c.[VIPId]
    WHERE a.AccountExpiryDate Between Cast(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(day, 30, GETDATE()) AS DATE);
```

Notes:

- *Always* explicitly list the columns you are inserting.  It is very easy to make a mistake if you do not do so.
- Only include the columns that actually have values; the rest will be defaulted to `NULL` (presumably).
- Give your tables meaningful table aliases such as `c` for `Customers`, not `VIP`.
- When using `DATEADD()`, explicitly write out the date part (`day` rather than `d`).
- Variables are not needed for this query.